# Native file chooser using input type file for Android 4.4.2 using VS 2013 Multi Device Hybrid Apps does not work

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, cordova-plugins, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I need to use the VS 2013 Multi Device Hybrid Apps which should on use of below html

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

be able to access the camera as well the other options (Gallery) currently when i add the above HTML only the gallery options are shown (Shown below).

[image]

I use an Android 4.4.2 phone .

I need to get the screen where the user can chose between a Camera/Gallery etc.

I have been trying to add this plugin to the Visual Studio https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser.git

by modifying the config.xml file

```
<vs:feature>https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser.git</vs:feature>
```

but i get this error "error: package R does not exist" . The defination in the plugin url say that we need to change the package name but i am not sure where should this be done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of fileChooser we need to set the R to work with the package.

"
    You will have to import your.package.name.R into the following java files:
    FileChooser.java 
    FileChooserActivity.java 
    FileListAdapter.java
    FileListFragment.java
    LocalStorageProvider.java
"

The FileChooser creator says that 
"automatically import your.package.name.R in the java files"
will be in the next version